# MVC Check model values in form using TryUpdateModel in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

I am currently following a tutorial on MVC 5, and I am stuck on how to perform validation checks on fields entered by the User without binding my fields in the Edit Method.

I have a Edit page already in place, but this binds all fields at the start - the tutorial which I'm following makes it clear that I **should not** do this.

My Original code is the following. Since I bind all of my fields at the start, I can perform checks by using vans.***fieldname*** as shown below with 'if (vans.AssetID == 20)'

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AssetID,Batch_Number,Customer_Account_Holder,Dealer_ID, ")] Vans__ vans)
    {
        if (vans.AssetID == 20) //Example - check if data entered for AssetID is 20
        {
          //do something
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(vans__).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vans__);
    }
```

In the tutorial that I'm following, I'm instructed not to bind everything at the start, but instead use code like the following:

```
    public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //In here vans is the original values and not from the form.
        Vans__ vans = db.Vans__.Find(id);

       //Here how can I check if AssetID is a certain number returned from the form?

        if (TryUpdateModel(vans, "", new string[] { "AssetID" }))
        {
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand the white-listing with the TryUpdateModel will be much easier and safer, I am just struggling to get to grips with how I get access to the data returned to the controller from the form.

**How can I access the model in order for me to add my own validation Checks?**

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Find a better tutorial.

Comment: @StephenMuecke would we be better binding to a smaller view model for the specific fields we wish to edit and then on the UpdateDB bind the view model to the DB entity model ? This is a practice we have seen as well. It does seem crazy with the bind method sending all 30 fields from an class when only 2 are to be updated for instance.

Comment: Yes, You should never use data models in views when editing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for that Stephen I am am more than happy to go along with your suggestion. We will stick with Bind but using a ViewModel for only the specific items we wish to edit/update.

Comment: @AndyDonegan, You do not need a `BindAttribute` when using a view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am confused, I thought BIND helped to ensure only the required data was accepted back ? or does it not matter now because we are not writing to the data model directly ?

Comment: It does not matter because you only map the properties from the view model to the data model that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

[The Microsoft tutorial is here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) (Disclaimer I work with James and asked him to learn by posting the question).

And write up from it below relating to why we should not be using the original BIND method which James has linked.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  var studentToUpdate = db.Students.Find(id);
  if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
   new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
  {
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and      if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
    }
  }
  return View(studentToUpdate);
}
```

These changes implement a security best practice to prevent overposting,  The scaffolder generated a Bind attribute and added the entity created by the model binder to the entity set with a Modified flag. That code is no longer recommended because the Bind attribute clears out any pre-existing data in fields not listed in the Include parameter. In the future, the MVC controller scaffolder will be updated so that it doesn't generate Bind attributes for Edit methods.

The new code reads the existing entity and calls  TryUpdateModel to update fields from user input in the posted form data. The Entity Framework's automatic change tracking sets the Modified flag on the entity. When the SaveChanges method is called, the Modified flag causes the Entity Framework to create SQL statements to update the database row.  Concurrency conflicts are ignored, and all columns of the database row are updated, including those that the user didn't change. (A later tutorial shows how to handle concurrency conflicts, and if you only want individual fields to be updated in the database, you can set the entity to Unchanged and set individual fields to Modified.)

As a best practice to prevent overposting, the fields that you want to be updateable by the Edit page are whitelisted in the TryUpdateModel parameters. Currently there are no extra fields that you're protecting, but listing the fields that you want the model binder to bind ensures that if you add fields to the data model in the future, they're automatically protected until you explicitly add them here.

As a result of these changes, the method signature of the HttpPost Edit method is the same as the HttpGet edit method; therefore you've renamed the method EditPost.

Comment: If you consider it's not an answer, please put it as a comment.

Comment: @Alpha_Wing kind of hard to help with the original question and past so much as a comment.